# Does Dataflow support parallel Datastore reads of namespaced entities?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow

According to [this question and answer from March](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29044270/issue-with-google-dataflow-using-datastoreio), some bugs in DatastoreIO make it impossible to read namespaced entities in parallel from within Dataflow. Have the bugs been addressed since then? Is it possible to read namespaced entities in parallel from the Datastore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parallel reading of namespaced entities is supported in DatastoreIO as of Dataflow SDK for Java 1.2.0. See the code and documentation [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/v1.2.0/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/DatastoreIO.java#L93).